# Pass props nicely to screens in react navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to pass a prop to the screen. When I try that inline e.g `(props) => <Comp {...props} {...customProps} />` I get a warning message, that I shouldn't parse functions to that component property. Okay. I thought I'll just create functions for every component which needs custom props. It is working, but is there a better solution? Here is my component:

````
export default function Loading() {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = React.useState(false);
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  const authService: AuthService = new AuthService();
  const authProps: IAuthProps = {
    authService
  };
  /**
   * Bind neccessary props to the login component
   * @param props Props
   */
  function LoginWithProps(props) {
    return <Login {...props} {...authProps} />;
  }
  /**
   * Bin neccessary props to the registration component
   * @param props Props
   */
  function RegistrationWithProps(props) {
    return <Registration {...props} {...authProps} />;
  }
  return (
    <>
      {/*Show the app, when logged in*/}
      {loggedIn === true ? (
        <View>
          <Text>Test</Text>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <Stack.Navigator
          initialRouteName="Login"
          screenOptions={{ headerShown: false, animationEnabled: false }}
        >
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginWithProps} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationWithProps} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```
````

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yours is not a good solution to the problem because new types of LoginWithProps and RegistrationWithProps components will be created every render, meaning old ones will be unmounting and new ones mounting every time. The same thing that happens when you pass a function, but without a warning

You can't pass props to these screens, as it is not the `Loading` component that is a direct parent to these screens. If you want to pass data to customize those components, you need to do it through navigation params, in 2 ways:

1. when navigating to a screen `navigation.navigate('Login', { param: 'hello' })`
2. by proviging initial params

.

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="Login"
  component={Loaing}
  initialParams={{ param: 'hello' }}
/>
```

And read it in `Login` with `props.route.params`

Note though this is called initialParams for a reason - they are not reactive, changing them after component is mounted has no effect (it is also possible to change them from inside component). If you want to pass reactive params, use React [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or Redux

[Passing parameters to routes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/)

Comment: Thank you, my problem is that I needed my `Home.js` to start off with a `handleLogin` function. This worked well for me

Comment: I did this approach already and worked fine. However, when using Deep Linking (with NextJS), I can't get it to work with Server Side Rendering, because I can't use `react-dom/server` that is required for `ServerContainer` component. I would just let route handled by NextJS, and just pass props to the Component. But when using initialParameters & linking props of `NavigationContainer`, then I get URL rewrite with params in Browser. I would prefer my props to stay away from Deep Linking.