# Component remounting on context update

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context, react-native-navigation

I've been trying to update a global state used by several screens on my app using react context, which seemed to be the advice I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60892552/pass-props-nicely-to-screens-in-react-navigation).

However every time the context is updated in the screen, it ends up unmounting and mounting again. How do I prevent this?

[Link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-clarke-lgzrks?file=/src/App.tsx). If you click the button you will see a new console log from my useEffect.

Code below:

```js
import React, {
  useContext,
  useState,
  useEffect,
  createContext,
  Dispatch,
  SetStateAction
} from "react";
import { Button } from "react-native";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

export type FlashcardWithScore = {
  frontSide: string;
  backSide: string;
  score: number;
};

interface WordListContextInterface {
  wholeWordList: FlashcardWithScore[];
  setWholeWordList: Dispatch<SetStateAction<FlashcardWithScore[]>>;
}

const wordListContext = createContext<WordListContextInterface | null>(null);

const Flashcards = () => {
  const appContext = useContext(wordListContext);
  if (!appContext) return null;
  const { wholeWordList, setWholeWordList } = appContext;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("component has been mounted");
  }, []);

  const handlePress = () => {
    setWholeWordList([
      ...wholeWordList,
      { frontSide: "foo", backSide: "bar", score: 0 }
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button title="press me to see issue!" onPress={handlePress} />
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [wholeWordList, setWholeWordList] = useState<FlashcardWithScore[]>([
    { frontSide: "more", backSide: "edits", score: 0 }
  ]);

  const RootStack = createStackNavigator();
  const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();

  const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
    return (
      <BottomTab.Navigator initialRouteName="Learn">
        <BottomTab.Screen
          name="Learn"
          component={Flashcards}
          options={{
            title: "Flashcard Learn"
          }}
        />
      </BottomTab.Navigator>
    );
  };
  return (
    <wordListContext.Provider value={{ wholeWordList, setWholeWordList }}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <RootStack.Navigator>
          <RootStack.Screen name="Root" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
        </RootStack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </wordListContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the definition of the `BottomTabNavigator` is not persisted between re-renders of the `App` component. Following the logic through from `App` render to button click to re-render:

1. App renders, creating a new `BottomTabNavigator` component while doing so
2. This BottomTabNavigator is rendered in the root stack screen
3. The context passed to the `Provider` is stored in local state in the `App` component with `useState`
4. Inside `Flashcards` when you click the button it calls `handlePress` which calls the context's `setWholeWordList` function, updating the context
5. In this case, the context is a local state in the `App` component, so it updates that state value and triggers a re-render in `App`
6. During re-rendering, it creates a brand new `BottomTabNavigator` component **in memory** and that one gets rendered
7. Since *technically* that `BottomTabNavigator` is a different one, React thinks it's a completely separate component, so "old" one is unmounted and this "new" one is mounted

The way to fix this is to ensure the `BottomTabNavigator` doesn't unnecessarily change between renders. One way is to, just like `Flashcards`, move it out of `App` into its own separate component definition. Another way is to memoize it with `useCallback`, i.e.

```
  const BottomTabNavigator = useCallback(() => {
    return (
      <BottomTab.Navigator initialRouteName="Learn">
        <BottomTab.Screen
          name="Learn"
          component={Flashcards}
          options={{
            title: "Flashcard Learn"
          }}
        />
      </BottomTab.Navigator>
    );
  }, []);
```

This means it won't get recreated in memory when `App` re-renders